# Type disabled problem in WebStorm about Vue3 Props

Tags: typescript, webstorm, vue-props

- declare `Props`

```js
import { ExtractPropTypes, PropType } from 'vue'

export const Props = {
  ocrName: {
    type: String as PropType<string>,
    default: () => 'Nicky',
  },
  age: {
    type: Number as PropType<number>,
    default: () => 18,
  },
} as const

export type OcrPropsType = ExtractPropTypes<typeof Props>
```

- use in `.vue` file

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { Props } from './props'
  const prop = defineProps(Props)
<script>
```

- WebStorm can not resolve the type in `template` although it works in VSCode:

[image]

```text
WebStorm: 2023.2 EAP
TypeScript: 5.1.6
Vue: 3.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `defineProps` like so:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
  ...
}>();
</script>
```

Comment: i think this is websotorm question,  this can not reslove problems